# Insert a date into my database via html form

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to insert a date into my database using  but cant seem to get it working. everything else will insert fine but when it comes to the date it reverts to the default 0000-00-00 like nothing has been entered. i am using the date data type

Heres my code

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  processInsertNewTrip();
 }
?>
<form action="index.php?page=Addtrip" method="post" novalidate>
 <div>
  <label for="name">Name: </label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
 </div>

 <div>
  <label for="days">Days: </label>
  <input type="number" name="days" id="days">
 </div>

 <div>
  <label for="difficulty">Difficulty: </label>
  <input type="text" name="difficulty" id="difficulty">
 </div>

 <div>
  <label for="price">Price: </label>
  <input type="number" name="price" id="price">
 </div>

 <div>
  <label for="date_1">Date 1: </label>
  <input type="date" name="date_1" id="date_1">
 </div>

 <div>
  <label for="date_2">Date 2: </label>
  <input type="date" name="date_2" id="date_2">
 </div>

 <div>
  <label for="max_people">Max People: </label>
  <input type="number" name="max_people" id="max_people">
 </div>

 <div>
  <label for="description">Description: </label>
  <textarea type="text" name="description" id="description"></textarea>
 </div>

 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Insert new trip">
</form>

    <?php
    function processInsertNewTrip(){
        global $dbCon;

        //Filter the data
        $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon, $_POST['name']);
        $days = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon, $_POST['days']);
        $difficulty = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon, $_POST['difficulty']);
        $price = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon, $_POST['price']);
        $date_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon, $_POST['date_1']);
        $date_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon, $_POST['date_2']);
        $max_people = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon, $_POST['max_people']);
        $description = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon, $_POST['description']);


        //Prepare SQL
        $SQL = "INSERT INTO trips (name, days, difficulty, price, date_1, date_2, max_people, description) VALUES ('$name', $days, '$difficulty', $price, $date_1, $date_2, $max_people, '$description')";
        if(mysqli_query($dbCon, $SQL)){
        //Find the ID of last inserted record
        $tripID = mysqli_insert_id($dbCon);

        //Redirect the user to the new trip page
        echo 'Success! you can <a href="index.php?page=Trips&trip-id='.$tripID.'">see your new trip</a>';
        }else{
        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $SQL. " . mysqli_error($dbCon);
        }
      }
?>
```

Comment: can you post the error message that sql is returning?

Comment: sql is showing no errors

Comment: why is your function not enclosed in PHP tags?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$date_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon, $_POST['date_1']);
$date_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon, $_POST['date_2']);
$date_1 = STR_TO_DATE('$date_1', '%m/%d/%Y');
$date_2 = STR_TO_DATE('$date_2', '%m/%d/%Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by using:

```
STR_TO_DATE('$date_1', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to change the format into `'Y-m-d'`

try this code. .

```
    $date_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon, $_POST['date_1']);
    $date_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon, $_POST['date_2']);

    $date_1 = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('$date_1'));
    $date_2 = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('$date_2'));
```